# How to statically link libevent with gcc while compiling?

Tags: c, static-linking, libevent

I have used event.h in on of my project but the server it has to run on does not support it. Moreover I can not install it also. Is there a way I can run my project with minimum modifications.

It has to be compiled statically linked in but how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean *the server it has to run on does not support it*? If a shared library is not installed, you can just build your project with the library statically linked in.

Alternatively, compile a shared library of libevent and include it with your application. I have had success using the RUNPATH headers in ELF binatries and shared libraries to put an application directory at the beginning of the dynamic library loading search path.

https://github.com/wavetossed/pybuild is an example of a build script for Python 2.7.2 and a couple dozen binary modules, which includes using libevent. Building just a single library using RUNPATH is much simpler.